# Class Not Found Exception X509UsernameRetrieverClassName Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication, servlets, client-certificates

I am trying to write a small Java application that authenticates users via Client certificate.
I have seen in the Tomcat that I can specify X509UsernameRetrieverClassName in the realm descriptor to tell tomcat to use my own implementation of the function that maps X509 certificates to user names.
The only thing that is not working is that it does not find the class I am specifying, even though I have a package and directly inside the class that implements the function org.apache.catalina.realm.X509UsernameRetriever.
After googling a lot I still did not find any answer to this problem.

Any help would be appreciated!

UPDATE:

I configure this class in my context.xml file for the webapp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/">
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm"
           X509UsernameRetrieverClassName="com.packagename.UserFromCert"
           pathname="conf/tomcat_users.xml"/>
</Context>
```

I have implemented the class as follows (just for testing)

```
package com.packgename;

import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

public class UserFromCert implements org.apache.catalina.realm.X509UsernameRetriever {

    @Override
    public String getUsername(X509Certificate x509Certificate) {
        System.out.println(x509Certificate.getSubjectDN().toString());
        System.out.println(x509Certificate.getSubjectX500Principal().getName());
        return x509Certificate.getSubjectDN().toString();
    }
}
```

The class that I am trying to implement is in the tomcat libraries.

Comment: It might be helpful if you include your Tomcat configuration file. In addition, how is this implementing class included? Is it in a WAR? Is it in Tomcat's lib directory?

Comment: where did you put your class? in your war?

Comment: I put my class directly in the package. It is deployed to tomcat inside the war i guess.

Answer (score 0):

I did something very similar with Tomcat 6.0 on a previous contract a couple of years ago. My memory is a little hazy and I left the code behind (sorry!), but I hope that this helps steer you (or someone else) in the right direction.

What I did was:

1) Import the Catalina source code into Eclipse
2) Create the new class(es) you need in a new file within the same project- mine was a custom implementation to map a value in the certificate's Distinguished Name to a UserName:

```
package org.apache.catalina.realm;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

public class CustomX509SubjectDnMapper implements X509UsernameRetriever {

    public String getUsername(X509Certificate clientCert) {
        return clientCert.getSubjectDN().getName().toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

3) Export the code to a new Catalina.jar file
4) Include this new Catalina.jar file in Tomcat's lib directory.

I can't remember whether I kept the custom implementation in the same package or not. I found that the key was to get the custom implementation into a the custom Catalina.jar which Tomcat could consume. It might also be possible to export a self-contained jar which references Catalina and import that into your Tomcat container.

Anyway, I hope that this helps in some capacity, and good luck.